# Fatal error: Uncaught error class not found, but the path and folder are correct

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with "Uncaught Error", even importing from the right folder, I already checked the path, but everything is correct.

In this part is where I need to use the class, I'm importing correctly:

```
<?php

use \App\Feed\Contabeis;

$obFeed = new Contabeis;
```

And here, I'm creating the class:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Feed;

class Contabeis {
  const FEED_URL = 'https://www.contabeis.com.br/rss/conteudo/';

  private $feed = null;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->loadFeed();
  }

  private function loadFeed() {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
      CURLOPT_URL => self::FEED_URL,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $this->parseXML($response);
  
  }

  private function parseXML($response) {
    if(!strlen($response)) return false;

    $this->feed = simplexml_load_string($response);

    return true;
  }

  public function getTitle() {
    return $this->feed->channel->title;
  }

  public function getItems() {
    return $this->feed->channel->item;
  }

}

?>
```

Message Error:

> [::1]:53700 [200]: GET / - Uncaught Error: Class "App\Feed\Contabeis" not found in /home/carlosszpiro/Documentos/Estudos/PHP/RSS/includes/feed.php:5
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/carlosszpiro/Documentos/Estudos/PHP/RSS/index.php(6): require()
>
> #1 {main} thrown in /home/carlosszpiro/Documentos/Estudos/PHP/RSS/includes/feed.php on line 5

Comment: Please add the full error message to the question.

Comment: Have you tried including the class file in the beginning of the function to see if you still get the error?

Comment: Yes, i tried including the class file

Comment: @arkascha this is a error in question